# Помогите с кодом на пайтоне tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

https://pastebin.com/cNGZbj5m
Помогите пожалуйста дополнить код чтобы было больше цветов(хотя бы +1цвет а там уже пойму). Или хотя бы поясните для дурака

Comment: http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt5/tetris/

Comment: И можно ли создавать игры в pyqt5? `Можно`.

Answer (score 1):

> Стоит ли делать программы с pyqt5 или лучше самому код писать с tkinter итд

Можно писать самому в tkinter, только вы будете ограничены по возможностям.

> И можно ли создавать игры в pyqt5?

Можно создавать игры в pyqt5, другой вопрос в том, что это не нужно, потому что помимо этого есть pygame(не плохая библиотека для своих поделок), можно даже использовать python в unity3d , или, если хотите писать новеллы с помощью ren'py.
Смысл в том, чтобы использовать каждый инструмент так, как его нужно использовать. Вы можете написать игру на pyqt5, просто это не будет иметь особого смысла ввиду затрат времени/сил.